# How to sort unique table in dataframe based on a single column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

have df with values

```
    0     |     1   |     2
0  sun    |   east  |   pass 
1  moon   |   west  |   pass
2  mars   |   north |   pass
3  saturn |   east  |   pass
4  neptune|   west  |   pass
```

Need to get the distinct df by looking the values of 1 column. Here in column 1 there are two east and two west and their 0 values are different.

the output should be

```
  0       |     1   |     2
0  sun    |   east  |   pass 
1  moon   |   west  |   pass
2  mars   |   north |   pass


              or


    0       |     1   |     2
0  saturn   |   east  |   pass 
1  neptune  |   west  |   pass
2  mars     |   north |   pass
```

so i output need only single value in 0 column not both. here need sun and moon (or) saturn and neptune.

Comment: Why is `north` row dropped?

Comment: edited. Plz check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need `groupby` with `join` - only necessary same values of `2` column per groups:

```
df = df.groupby([1,2], sort=False)[0].apply(' (or) '.join).reset_index().sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
                   0      1     2
0    sun (or) saturn   east  pass
1  moon (or) neptune   west  pass
2               mars  north  pass
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion editied please check. meant any of them. but only one should be present.

Comment: @hukkemaaru - Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) like `df = df.drop_duplicates([0,1])` or `df = df.drop_duplicates([0,1], keep='last')`

Comment: @hukkemaaru - oops, need `df = df.drop_duplicates([1])`

Comment: onkly test column `1` for dupes